# Duplicate files copied in APK LICENSE (same file)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting a duplicate files error when attempting to build with Gradle.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':pauwowandroid:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK LICENSE
    File 1: /Users/jasonrobinson/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.sisu.inject/cglib/2.2.1-v20090111/7ce5e983fd0e6c78346f4c9cbfa39d83049dda2/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar
    File 2: /Users/jasonrobinson/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.sonatype.sisu.inject/cglib/2.2.1-v20090111/7ce5e983fd0e6c78346f4c9cbfa39d83049dda2/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar
```

This is different from other similar errors in that it's complaining the duplicate is in the same file. These are my exclusions:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
```

I still get this error. It's with one particular dependency: Mockito. If I remove that dependency, the error goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following exclude:

```
exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
```

This should fix it.

Comment: Just figured this out as you posted. I needed to exclude 'LICENSE' and exclude 'NOTICE'. For this library, they weren't inside the META-INF folder.